# Question on sql syntax: *=

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql

I have some older (broken) code that has a join using a *=

```
table1.ID *= table2.ID
```

Is this a left outer join or a right outer join?  (My error message indicates it is one of those)

Comment: How about implied inner joins as well :) SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID ... so many ways to skin a cat in SQL.

Comment: It's better to use `FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID`, because joins are executed before the `WHERE` clause. Plus it's more maintainable and readable.

Comment: I totally agree ... I'm just saying they give so many ways to do the same thing. For example, you could have just as easily said FROM table2 RIGHT JOIN table1 ON table2.ID = table1.ID ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
*= (LEFT OUTER JOIN)

=* (RIGHT OUTER JOIN)
```

But rather make use of the `LEFT/RIGHT JOINS`

Comment: And this syntax should never be used anyway as it will not always correctly resolve to an outer join, sometimes it is a cross join. BOL as far back as SQL SErver 2000 says this syntax is unreliable and it is deprecated for the next version.

Answer (score 1):

`*=` indicates left-outer join and `=*` indicates right-outer join.

#### EDIT:

I had my joins mixed up, have been corrected.

Comment: astander wins - http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/13070;pt=12475

Comment: yeah I had typed too fast to answer, and didn't realize what I had wrote for what syntax, gg me.

Comment: Good -- because I had two opposite answers, both from people with a lot of rep and badges, so I've been waiting for the right one to bubble to the top.

Comment: Haha yeah, good thinking. I jotted down the answer and went to a different tab on my browser and when I had returned I noticed a downvote and then I knew what I had done.

Comment: Google search doesn't work so well on a couple of characters, or perhaps I have poor google-fu.

Comment: @Nissan Fan: Thanks, I appreciate it. I couldn't react fast enough to save the answer.

Comment: @thursdaygeek, for future reference, google does not work well with symbols, i.e (`*` and `=`) but spelling them out could help, i.e. (`asterisk` and `equals`)

Comment: @Anthony Forloney - Thank you!  That gave me the right answer right away.  I'll remember that next time.  (This still gives a better answer, with some reasonable examples as well.)

Comment: @thursdaysgeek, not a problem anytime, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

**please** replace that with modern `LEFT OUTER JOIN .. ON` syntax!!

left outer join `*=`
right outer join `=*`

Answer (score 0):

table1.ID *= table2.ID if table1 & table2 are columns then in sqlserver it will give error in correct syntax it is better to use inner join