# Why use "=+" and "=*" in "WHERE " clause?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have  issue related database connection in  java class,i don't know why use this  "=+" and "=*" in "WHERE " clause.

Here's an example:

```
String where = null;
if (isOracleConnectionCache()) {
    where = "ValidInfo.InfoCode = FolderInfo.InfoCode AND ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup =+ ValidInfo.InfoGroup AND FolderInfo.FolderRSN = ?";
} else {
    where = "ValidInfo.InfoCode = FolderInfo.InfoCode AND ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup =* ValidInfo.InfoGroup AND FolderInfo.FolderRSN = ?";
}
```

Can anyone tell me ?

I have three question :

(1) What do "*" and "+" signs denote ?

(2) how do these `=+` and `=*` work in the WHERE clause  ?

(3)how it is compare with two table ?

Comment: So is this Oracle OR MySQL OR is it common to both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server \*= Operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983862/sql-server-operator)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt how it is duplicate ?

Comment: Because the question linked to is about the =* operator.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - But it doesn't cover the `=+` operator. Though I strongly suspect that this isn't a real operator anyway. And that `x =+ y` is just being treated as `x = (+y)`.

Comment: Assuming `=+` is supposed to create an outer join in Oracle (which it doesn't) both versions should be removed and replaced with the standard ANSI `LEFT JOIN` syntax. Oracle and Microsoft highly recommend that as well. Microsoft deprecated the `=*` operator whereas Oracle only "recommends" to use the new syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as already explained by others, the `=*` operator in SQL Server indicates an outer join.

However, in Oracle `=+` is not an operator at all.  It appears that `ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup =+ ValidInfo.InfoGroup` is actually parsed as `ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup = (+ ValidInfo.InfoGroup)`, where `+` is the unary identity operator.

Since this code appears to be an attempt to write an outer join depending on which database is being used, it is incorrect when used in Oracle - it is actually doing a normal join.  The proper way to write this condition in Oracle's custom syntax would be `ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup = ValidInfo.InfoGroup (+)`.

It would perhaps be better to use ANSI SQL join syntax to indicate the outer join, which I believe would remove the need to test which database is being used.

Thanks to Martin and Nicholas for helpful comments on the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

`=*` does OUTER JOIN in SQL Server

**UPDATE**

`(+)` = does OUTER JOIN in Oracle

I dont know what =+ does sorry for the confusion

Comment: A brief experiment in Oracle seems to indicate that this is incorrect.  Can you give a documentation reference?

Comment: `=*` doesn't do `OUTER JOIN` in *standard* SQL. It is deprecated [right outer join](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2541021/73226) syntax in SQL Server.

Comment: @DaveCosta (+) is indeed (outdated) Oracle syntax for an outer join, see http://docs.oracle.com/html/E26088_01/queries006.htm

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - But in parentheses. The code in the question is `ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup =+ ValidInfo.InfoGroup`

Comment: @MartinSmith Sure, but as far as I understand it, DaveCosta was asking about the (+) operator mentioned in the answer, not about the =+ in the original question.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - No. Dave's comment was left before this was edited when the answer asserted `"=+" does OUTER JOIN in Oracle`

Comment: @MartinSmith You're right, I hadn't noticed that the post had been edited. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing but Outer Join in Oracle and MS-SQL Let us suppose i one table record is deleted and corresponding value is NULL so when You will compare with `==` from my understand it will create issue so we can use Outer Join like you mentioned in Your question.

Comment: I've tried doing some joins in Oracle using `=+` as an operator.  It does not function as an outer join in my attempts.  Can you provide an example or a link to documentation explaining the use of this operator?  It seems to be a valid operator in Oracle SQL but so far I don't see how it is different from a normal `=` operator.

Comment: @DaveCosta - It could just be `=` followed by unary `+` then?

Comment: I am using in my application same as mentioned above

Comment: `This is nothing but Outer Join in Oracle` No, `=+` operator is not a valid Oracle operator and has nothing to do with outer join. Indication of outer join(not ANSI SQL) in Oracle would be column name followed by `(+)` operator. Conditions `col =+ col` or `col =- col` will work, simply because plus or minus sign in those conditions are treated as unary arithmetic operators and condition `col =* col` will fail.

Comment: `==` is invalid in SQL. It's **not** the equals operator.