# Alternative to *= for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Is there any alternative to use `*=` for queries in SQL Server 2012? Queries with `*=` work fine in SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005 but do not work in SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT
  T.DOC_TYPE, T.DOC_NO, T.DOC_DATE, T.LR_NO, T.LR_DATE,
  T.DOC_REF, T.USER_ID, T.TRUCK_NO, P.PARTY_NAME,  TA.WBSLIP_NO, 
  TA.RATE, TA.SHORTAGE, TA.OTHER, TA.SERTAX, TA.PAPAMT, TA.BROK,
  I.IM_CHLQTY, I.IM_RXDQTY, I.IM_QTY, I.IM_REF,
  (SELECT PA.PARTY_NAME 
   FROM PARTYMST PA, TRINVS 
   WHERE TRINVS.DOC_TYPE = ?DOCTYPE 
     AND TRINVS.DOC_NO BETWEEN ?FDOCNO AND ?TDOCNO 
     AND PA.PARTY_ST + PA.PARTY_NO = TRINVS.TRNP_ST + TRINVS.TRNP_NO) TRNP_NAME
FROM 
  TRINVS T, TRINVSA TA, IMTRANS I, IMTRANSA IA, PARTYMST P 
WHERE
  T.DOC_TYPE = '   30' 
  AND T.DOC_NO = 'byrod125378' I.DOC_TYPE + I.DOC_NO = T.DOC_TYPE + T.DOC_NO 
  AND IA.DOC_TYPE + IA.DOC_NO = I.DOC_TYPE + I.DOC_NO 
  AND I.DOC_TYPE *= TA.DOC_NO 
  AND P.PARTY_ST + P.PARTY_NO = T.PARTY_ST + T.PARTY_NO 
ORDER BY 
  T.DOC_NO
```

I got error:

> incorrect syntax near *=.

Why can I not use `*=` for joins in SQL Server 2012?? Query works fine in SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005. Is there any alternative to `*=` for SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Usually [LEFT JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541004/question-on-sql-syntax).

Comment: Since the **ANSI / ISO SQL Standard 92** (yes - **1992** - more than 20 years ago!) - the proper JOIN syntax for **any** relational database is to use `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc

Comment: do i need to use left join for each and every field??

Comment: *= works w. SQL Server 2008 only in compatibility mode (SQL 2000).

Comment: You could use this as an introduction to the proper join syntax: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html. Once you understand the basic concept, I believe you'll see how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll take a stab, although the `*=` syntax is not very obvious when it comes to rewriting them as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so you'll really want to test that it's equivalent;

```
...
FROM TRINVS T
INNER JOIN PARTYMST P      
  ON P.PARTY_ST + P.PARTY_NO = T.PARTY_ST + T.PARTY_NO
INNER JOIN IMTRANS I       
  ON I.DOC_TYPE + I.DOC_NO = T.DOC_TYPE + T.DOC_NO 
INNER JOIN IMTRANSA IA     
  ON IA.DOC_TYPE + IA.DOC_NO = I.DOC_TYPE + I.DOC_NO
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRINVSA TA 
  ON I.DOC_TYPE = TA.DOC_NO
WHERE T.DOC_TYPE = '   30' AND T.DOC_NO = 'byrod125378'
ORDER BY T.DOC_NO
```

As a sadly somewhat incomplete summary, what you want to start with to move the join conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of a `JOIN` is;

- `*=` comparisons should be written as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with an `=` comparison in the `ON` clause.
- `=*` comparisons should be rewritten as `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` with an `=` comparison in the `ON` clause.
- `=` comparisons not involving a left- or right joined table should be rewritten as `INNER JOIN` with the comparison moved to the `ON` clause.
- `=` comparisons involving right- or left joined tables are normally moved to the corresponding `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` `ON` clause, but this is really where the mapping is no longer straight forward and may need further analysis/testing to be equivalent.

Comment: Where the `JOIN` alone could also be written (more clearly, in my opinion) as `INNER JOIN` (and `LEFT JOIN` could be also spelled out as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - that way it's clear right from the get go that you're using `INNER` and `OUTER` joins here)

Comment: Seconding @marc_s, as the OP is new to the concept, it would be better to show them the difference properly.

Comment: @marc_s Point taken, although I personally find the longer syntax harder to read.

Comment: i have bunch of queries. this is a sample query. so is there any standard solution?

Comment: @neeldesai The closest I have seen to a tutorial on this is [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/Become-an-ANSI-star.doc) (DOC format), but I don't know of any tool that helps.